# Can this PageAdapter behaviour be achieved in iOS?

Tags: android, ios, user-interface

On Twitter for Android there is a bar at the top of the display where the user can swipe left and right between three different screens: Home, Discover and Activity (see image 1).

[image]

As they do so, the small blue line moves in real time to underneath the name of the screen that has been selected (see image 2).

[image]

When the user scrolls downwards, the entire bar collapses to the size of the blue line and it remains that way until the user scrolls up again.

Can this be achieved in xCode, ideally in Storyboard? If not, what is the best alternative?

Apologies for the massive images...

Comment: You could do it in iOS using code but I am not sure about storyboard  but you will still end up using code to do the animations. If I were to do it.. I would probably start with 2 scroll views, one for the titles and other one for the main content. Main content's scrollview will have paging enabled and scrolling that will move the blue bar on the title view to X pixels. Scrolling up on the main content (using contentOffset), if the main content->scrollview.contentOffset.y < some pixel value then shorten the frame of the title view. That would be my approach using all code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have built this as an ios feature before (also an android dev so I know where you are coming from).

Here is the DIY way;

Use a UIScrollView and with the pagingEnabled property set to YES. Typically a UIPageControl is used along with it.

Here is a Library that does it for you;

https://github.com/monsieurje/ICViewPager

Hope this has answered all your problems.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is very helpful. Is there a way to make the red line move in time with the content view if you drag the content view?

Comment: unfortunately there is no way I know of to do using that tab bar... But... you could fake it by having a view inside with a red background color. (if this doesn't make sense I can clarify further).

Comment: SO a UIScrollview allows you to swipe around whatever 'ContentSize'(scrollView.contentSize) that you set. This is different to frame size which is used as the box which you display. The contentsize is the maximum scrollable area basically. So what you want to do is add a bar at the bottom inside the scrollview which follows the scrollview(containing your tab titles) and a red pointer which sticks to the position of the currently active tab.

Comment: I think that makes sense. Certainly enough for me to be getting on with. Thanks very much!

Comment: No problem at all. May I suggest changing your question title to 'Can this PageAdapter behaviour be achieved in iOS (xcode)?' for a greater page hit therefore more brilliant answers :)

Comment: @Sebastian Can you please tell me how to handle the red line move time with the content view if we drag the content view. I am also using ICViewpager in my app but i am not able to achieve this requirment